# Blazor Server side, ExternalRegister buttons at .razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, blazor, blazor-server-side

Is possible to have the buttons "External Registration" placed inside .razor page (server side)?

The below code is from ExternalRegister.cshtml but I would like to have that two registration buttons (Google, Facebook) as part of the Start.razor page. Is that possible?

```
@model Aplication.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.ExternalRegisterModel
<form id="external-account" asp-page="./ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div>
        <p>
            @foreach (var provider in Model.ExternalLogins)
            {
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
            }
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried even iframe, <iframe src = "/ ExternalRegisteration" title = "ExternalRegisteration"> </iframe>, but even if is displayed correctly still dosn't work when button click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to have the buttons in your razor page.

Of course, to do this, you need to be able to enumerate the available providers, which means you need to pass them in to your Blazor application from
_Host.cshtml (or wherever you host the Blazor application)

*note: you cannot pass a list of `AuthenticationScheme` because .NET will not serialise them, which is why I transform them into a DTO `ExternalProvider`*

```cs
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager
@{
  var state = new InitialApplicationState
  {
      XsrfToken = Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken,
      ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync())
        .ToList()
        .Select(scheme=>
           new ExternalProvider {Name=scheme.Name, DisplayName=scheme.DisplayName}
         )
  };
}
<component type="typeof(App)" param-InitialState="state" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
```

The `InitialApplicationState` and `ExternalProvider` are simple DTO classes

```cs
public class InitialApplicationState
{
    public string XsrfToken { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ExternalProvider> ExternalLogins { get; set; }
}
public class ExternalProvider
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, you need to receive this data in your Blazor code as a `Parameter` on the `App.razor` component

```
@inject InitialApplicationState InitialStateService

@code {
  [Parameter] public InitialApplicationState InitialState { get; set; } = default;

  protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
    InitialStateService.XsrfToken = InitialState.XsrfToken;
    InitialStateService.ExternalLogins = InitialState.ExternalLogins;
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
  }
}
```

All we are doing here is declaring the `Parameter` `InitialState` that will receive our `InitialApplicationState` - and then we store that state in a service `InitialStateService` which is configured in `startup.cs` as a Scoped dependency.

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<InitialApplicationState>();
```

Now, we have a service in our DI container for Blazor that contains a list of available external authentication providers and our forgery protection token.

We can inject the `InitialApplicationState` anywhere we need it in Blazor e.g. `Index.razor` and enumerate the `ExternalLogins` to render buttons

The form is declared slightly differently in Blazor as we don't have the `asp*` directives:

```html
@inject InitialApplicationState InitialStateService

<form id="external-account" 
      action="/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin" 
      method="post">
  <div>
    <p>
      @foreach (var provider in InitialStateService.ExternalLogins)
      {
        <button type="submit" 
                name="provider" 
                value="@provider.Name" 
                title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">
          @provider.DisplayName
        </button>
      }
    </p>
  </div>
  <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden"
        value="@InitialStateService.XsrfToken">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best strategy is to define two OnPost method in your Razor PageModel (Code-Behind). For example:

```
    public void OnPostFaceBook(ExternalLogin provider)
{
    //your code here
}

    public void OnPostGoogle(ExternalLogin provider)
{
    //your code here
}
```

And in your .cshtml file place two separate form for each one, and add parameter
**asp-page-handler**
to each submit button. For example:

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="FaceBook" value="FaceBook" asp-page-handler="FaceBook">Log in using your FaceBook account</button>
```

and in other form:

```
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Google" value="Google" asp-page-handler="Google">Log in using your Google account</button>
```